# Make the table colums to show one below another on smaller screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress

See this sample website

```
http://utim.in
```

the 3 column table in this website is not responsive. my question is how to make it break and show as one column below the other like the galley should come second and so on. is there any css hack for adding in the @media screen section?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7enehfo3/ ?

Comment: Don't use tables for layout purposes. The last time this was legitimate was more than 15 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your table layouts for divs and use float, inline-block or flexbox for align them in a row. Html tables is a worst aproach for layouts.